# How can I access the data returned by the function funnode?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, indexing

I'm using the CompEcon package produced to solve a dynamic programming problem. I've used the builtin function [`funnode`](https://github.com/apb296/robust-learning-insurance/blob/master/Matlab/compecon2011/CEtools/funnode.m) to produce vectors and arrays. When the function outputs vectors, I am able to access the elements of the vectors without any trouble. For example:

```
test2=funnode(test)
```

returns

```
test2 =
    33.4937
    250.0000
    466.5064
```

This is great, I can access the first element by `test2(1)`. However, when I try to produce an array as an output, I get an object that I haven't seen before:

```
>> RQ_nodes = funnode(fspace)
RQ_nodes = 
    [3x1 double]    [3x1 double]
>> RQ_nodes(1)
ans = 
    [3x1 double]
>> RQ_nodes(1,1)
ans = 
    [3x1 double]
```

`RQ_nodes` looks like a 2x3 array to me. How can I access one of the elements in the first column?

Answer (score 3):

The output is a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), so you have to use curly braces to [access the contents of a cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html#d119e31399). For example, this will give you the first vector:

```
vec1 = RQ_nodes{1};
```

And this will give you the first element of the first vector:

```
elem1 = RQ_nodes{1}(1);
```